# Multiple FPGAs with flash

Tags: jtag, openocd

i have a board with two FPGAs (Xilinx 7-series xc7k160t) and each of them has its own flash memory.
To reflect this in my config file i used

```
... stuff for the JTAG interface

set CHIPNAME fpga_A
source [find cpld/xilinx-xc7.cfg]
source [find cpld/jtagspi.cfg]

set CHIPNAME fpga_B
source [find cpld/xilinx-xc7.cfg]
source [find cpld/jtagspi.cfg]

source [find fpga/xilinx-dna.cfg]
source [find fpga/xilinx-xadc.cfg]

set flash_bitstream "/home/ubuntu/bscan_spi_xc7k160t.bit"

... helper functions like program_Flash
```

I can write bitstreams to the FPGA itself and also read their temperature and DNA.
Unfortunately, writing to the flash memories doesn't work.
As my proxy bitstream I use 'bscan_spi_xc7k160t.bit' from https://github.com/quartiq/bscan_spi_bitstreams

Can anybody tell me the commands to program the flash memory of fpga_A and fpga_B. I tried the following.

```
proc program_Flash {tap_name bitstream} {
  init
  global _FLASHNAME
  set _FLASHNAME $tap_name.spi
  jtagspi_init [tapID_to_index $tap_name] $::flash_bitstream
  echo "init done"
  echo "_FLASHNAME = $_FLASHNAME"
  jtagspi_program $bitstream 0
  echo "program done"
  xc7_program $tap_name
}

proc tapID_to_index {tap_name} {
  if [string equal $tap_name "fpga_A"] {
    return 0
  } else {
    return 1
  } 
}
```

But this can only transfer the bitstream into fpga_B and then fails during the flash verification inside jtagsspi_program. Flashing for fpga_A fails right at the beginning and doesn't alter the memory.

**------  EDIT**
I'm trying to use openocd not Vivado. The boards have been working fine with Vivado for years. The bitstream transfer directly into the FPGA is working with openocd as well, it's just the programming of the flash memory using jtagspi and an intermediate proxy bitstream that's causing trouble.
I have to switch to openocd as the FPGAs are connected to a system running ARM and unfortunately there is no ARM version of the Vivado hwserver.

The FPGA are visible in openocd via "scan_chain". The flash memories are also created by jtagspi.cfg and show up in "flash banks". The programming sequence

Flashing the first FPGA fails completly:

```
> program_Flash fpga_A /home/ubuntu/current.bit
pld load 0 /home/ubuntu/bscan_spi_xc7k160t.bit
reset halt
JTAG tap: fpga_A.tap tap/device found: 0x0364c093 (mfg: 0x049 (Xilinx),
part: 0x364c, ver: 0x0)
JTAG tap: fpga_B.tap tap/device found: 0x0364c093 (mfg: 0x049 (Xilinx),
part: 0x364c, ver: 0x0)
flash probe fpga_A.spi
Found flash device 'sp s25fl128s' (ID 0x00182001)
init done
_FLASHNAME = fpga_A.spi
flash write_image erase /home/ubuntu/current.bit 0
Unknown flash device (ID 0x003f0000)
auto_probe failed
auto erase enabled
```

Flashing the second FPGAs memory works partially:

```
 > program_Flash fpga_B /home/ubuntu/current.bit
pld load 1 /home/ubuntu/bscan_spi_xc7k160t.bit
reset halt
JTAG tap: fpga_A.tap tap/device found: 0x0364c093 (mfg: 0x049 (Xilinx),
part: 0x364c, ver: 0x0)
JTAG tap: fpga_B.tap tap/device found: 0x0364c093 (mfg: 0x049 (Xilinx),
part: 0x364c, ver: 0x0)
flash probe fpga_B.spi
Found flash device 'sp s25fl128s' (ID 0x00182001)
init done
_FLASHNAME = fpga_B.spi
flash write_image erase /home/ubuntu/current.bit 0
Found flash device 'sp s25fl128s' (ID 0x00182001)
Found flash device 'sp s25fl128s' (ID 0x00182001)
Found flash device 'sp s25fl128s' (ID 0x00182001)
sector 0 took 391 ms
sector 1 took 450 ms
sector 2 took 452 ms
sector 3 took 439 ms
... (removed to shorten log)
sector 102 took 459 ms
flash verify_bank fpga_B.spi /home/ubuntu/current.bit 0
Found flash device 'sp s25fl128s' (ID 0x00182001)
program done
Invalid command argument
Tap: fpga_B unknown
```

The start up of openocd looks shows no errors

```
ubuntu@arm:~$ openocd -f openocd_test.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-01383-gd46f28c2e-dirty (2020-08-18-17:07)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
create fpga_A.proxy testee -chain-position fpga_A.tap
flash bank fpga_A.spi jtagspi 0 0 0 0 fpga_A.proxy 0x02
create fpga_B.proxy testee -chain-position fpga_B.tap
flash bank fpga_B.spi jtagspi 0 0 0 0 fpga_B.proxy 0x02
Info : Found Xilinx XVC/PCIe capability at offset: 0x0
Info : This adapter doesn't support configurable speed
Info : JTAG tap: fpga_A.tap tap/device found: 0x0364c093 (mfg: 0x049 (Xilinx), part: 0x364c, ver: 0x0)
Info : JTAG tap: fpga_B.tap tap/device found: 0x0364c093 (mfg: 0x049 (Xilinx), part: 0x364c, ver: 0x0)
allow_remote
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
```

Comment: Do you have a schematic of the board? What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are there any error messages?

Comment: I've used vivaldo for a little while and it seems to me this is a matter of arranging your hardware design to fit with their drivers and software used to update board non-volatile memories used to initialize at power-on. There is probably a paper on this. If you paid them money, not using WebPack, then make them help you with this. Otherwise, try their forum or else try Digilent's forum.

Comment: UG470 is the user configuration guide he probably needs to examine.

Comment: @jonk the asker is trying to use OpenOCD, not the Xilinx jtag software.  Though indeed, seeing if it works with the Xilinx software would be a good validation of the board design.  Even though jtag was designed to support multiple chips, in practice that's often best avoided with a connector/chain per target preferable.  I'd also consider trying to bypass one of the chips so there's just one in the chain and see if OpenOCD at least works in that simplified case first (hopefully there are some SMD resistor packages that could serve as disconnects, if not major lesson learned for next time!)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for the correction and the expansion of details. Whether or not that helps the OP, it helps me. Appreciated!

Comment: I made an update to avoid further confusion. This is not about Vivado, but OpenOCD. Programming works with Vivado, so it's most likely not an electrical issue.

Comment: And if you try to program the flash of only *one* FPGA with OpenOCD?  Also you should use verbose debug to figure out the "invalid command argument".   Chances are this can work, but you'll probably have to work for it, modifying scripts or possible even openocd source code.   Also do some searching online for any history of people trying to do this with openocd, whatever (partial?) support there is didn't just appear, someone authored it.

Comment: I only program the flash module of one FPGA at a time, never both at the same time.
The flash memory is directly attached to the FPGA, but not the JTAG chain. Therefore the FPGA has to be reprogrammed with a temporary bitstream and can then forward the actual data to the flash memory.